# Based on api response call another api - nested api in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I am not an expert in Scala and this might be trivial scenario, tried a lot but it doesn't seem to work.

Basically based on a condition I need to call an api and based on the response of the api I need to call another api

```
def getVal (o: String, site: Option[String]): Future[T] {
    val sp = site match {
       case some(s) => apiCall1(s) // The response here is Future[Option[T]]
       case _ => None // What should be here is also a question
    }

    sp match { // I think the issue is this match
       case some(sp1) => {
         //flow never comes here
         sp1.asInstanceOf(Future[T])
       }
       case _ => apiCall2(o) // The response here is Future[T]
    }
}
```

The response of above method is always what apiCall2 returns. I kept debug statements and I can see sp1 has a value for Future[Success[Some[T]]].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I don't know the behavior of the underlying APIs, I mocked the underlying APIs like this:

```scala
def apiCall1(string: String): Future[Option[String]] = {
  if (string == "") Future(None) else Future(Some(s"Response 1: $string"))
}

def apiCall2(string: String): Future[String] = {
  Future(s"Response 2: $string")
}
```

The final result will depend on the behavior of the underlying APIs, but this implementation will cover all cases.

You should implement the `getVal` function like this to use the result of the first API properly:

```scala
def getVal(o: String, site: Option[String]): Future[String] = {
  val sp = site match {
    case Some(s) => apiCall1(s)
    case _ => Future.successful(None)
  }

  sp.flatMap {
    case Some(spValue) => Future(spValue)
    case _ => apiCall2(o)
  }
}
```

Now, if you run these functions with these inputs:

```scala
getVal("O", None).onComplete { result => println("O", None, result) }
getVal("O", Some("")).onComplete { result => println("O", Some(""), result) }
getVal("O", Some("Input")).onComplete { result => println("O", Some("Input"), result) }
```

You will get these outputs:

```
(O,None,Success(Response 2: O))
(O,Some(),Success(Response 2: O))
(O,Some(Input),Success(Response 1: Input))
```

Comment: Yes I was only looking for conceptual reply, my question looked so funny when I realised these are promises and we need to wait for the response. Unfortunately I was able to make this work using `andThen` before seeing ur reply. But I am pretty sure ur solution will work as well, Thanks

Comment: You don't need the whole `spResponse => spResponse match {` noise, you can just pattern match directly on the body.

Comment: Thank you @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. I wanted to use the simplest format. Otherwise, I would use for comprehension and print the result inside the for comprehension.